# Adjoint theorem for loop and suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology

Ref: [Davis and Kirk, Lecture Notes on Algebraic Topology](http://www.indiana.edu/~jfdavis/teaching/m623/book.pdf)

On pp.114 it is the adjoint theorem for the category of Hausdorff compactly generated spaces: for $X,Y,Z$ compactly generated $f(x,y) \mapsto \tilde{f}(x)(y)$ gives a homeomorphism $$ \text{Map}((X \times Y),Z) \longrightarrow \text{Map}(X,\text{Map}(Y,Z)) $$

On pp.137 restricting to pointed maps we obtain its based version which states that there exists the following homeomorphism $$ \text{Map}_*((X \times Y),Z) \longrightarrow \text{Map}_*(X,\text{Map}_*(Y,Z)) $$

On pp.138 substituting in the definition of suspension $\Sigma{X} = S^1 \times X/S^1 \vee X = S^1 \wedge X$ and the definition of based loop space $\Omega{X}$ = Map$_*(S^1,X)$ we obtain the following homeomorphism $$ \text{Map}_*(\Sigma{X},Y) \longrightarrow \text{Map}_*(X,\Omega{Y}) $$ which means that loop and suspension are adjoint

My question pertains to the last step where we substitute in the definition of suspension $\Sigma{X} = S^1 \times X/S^1 \vee X = S^1 \wedge X$.  It is really not a direct product between $S^1$ and $X$ but the theorem seems to suggest that the quotient does not matter.  I don't understand why.

**PS**: It turns out that the isomorphism that I copied from pp.137 is wrong!  We can't simply add the subscripts to indicate that we are considering basepoint preserving maps.  We should also change $X \times Y$ to $X \wedge Y$.  For reason please refer to Mike's answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second display in your question, the one allegedly copied from page 137, is incorrect.  In place of $X\times Y$ it should have $X\land Y$ (see Theorem 6.33).  This correction resolves the suspension problem, because $\Sigma X=S^1\land X$.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing that out Andreas!  But that is a very easy to commit mistake (just adding subscripts) and I would rather leave it there to warn the new learners!

Comment: @PhysicsMath You should at least add a note that it's incorrect as stated.

Comment: @MikeMiller: I said it in the end, in the "PS" section.  I hope that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

One should also have the property that if $\text{Map}(X,A;B)$ denotes the space of maps $X \to B$ that are constant on $A$, $\text{Map}(X,A;B) \cong \text{Map}(X/A,B)$ for a closed subset $A \subset X$. This implies from the product formula that $\text{Map}_*(X \wedge Y, Z) \cong \text{Map}_*(X, \text{Map}_*(Y,Z))$, by (as you say) quotienting: take $A = X \vee Y$.

To unpack: consider the subset of $\text{Map}_*(X \times Y,Z)$ consisting of maps that are constant (say $z_0$) when restricted to $X \vee Y$ i.e. any map $f$ in that subset satisfies $f(x_0,y) = f(x,y_0) = z_0$, denote by $\tilde{f}$ the image of $f$ under the map $\text{Map}(X \times Y,Z) \to \text{Map}(X,\text{Map}(Y,Z))$, then

(1) $f(x_0,y) = z_0$ implies that $\tilde{f}(x_0)$ is a constant map in $\text{Map}(Y,Z)$ thus $\tilde{f}(x_0)$ is the basepoint of $\text{Map}(Y,Z)$, hence requiring that $\tilde{f}: X \to \text{Map}(Y,Z)$ is basepoint preserving is equivalent to requiring that $f(x_0,y) = z_0$

(2) $f(x,y_0) = z_0$ implies that $\tilde{f}(x)(y_0) = z_0$ $\forall x$, which is exactly the condition that the image of $\tilde{f}: X \to \text{Map}(Y,Z)$ lies within $\text{Map}_*(Y,Z)$---the subset of basepoint preserving maps of $\text{Map}(Y,Z)$

combining the above two conditions we see that maps in $\text{Map}_*(X,\text{Map}_*(Y,Z))$ correspond precisely to those in $\text{Map}_*(X \times Y,Z)$ that are constant when restricted to $X \vee Y$

Comment: Hi Mike, could you be more detailed about how you go from $\text{Map}(X,A;B) \cong \text{Map}(X/A,B)$ to $\text{Map}_*(X \vee Y,Z) \cong \text{Map}_*(X,\text{Map}(Y,Z))$?  That is where I am stuck with.  In particular what is $A$ in the product formula?

Comment: @PhysicsMath I updated the answer. You need to be more careful where you write the basepoint symbol: it should appear twice in the RHS of your second isomorphism in your comment. Also, in your original question, you forgot to put a smash product on the left side of the based case; and smash is denoted by \wedge, not \vee.

Comment: Got it Mike!  Sorry about the notation mistake.  I have rephrased your answer quite a bit so as to let unsophisticated physicists can understand.  Please check whether there is any mistake or typo!

Comment: @PhysicsMath Looks fine. No need to call anyone unsophisticated. Sorry if my original wording was hard to read.

Comment: Your answer is at least comprehensible to me Mike! I did not imply anything.  No need to apologize and thanks a lot for patiently unpacking every detail!